# Reading ini file onCreate event causes 8 second delay

Tags: delphi, profiling, delphi-2009, ini

I have some complex software, and i whittled the delay in it to this piece of code:

```
procedure Tform1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inherited;
  with TIniFile.Create(Path + '\FileName.INI') do
    try
       CheckBox1.Checked :=ReadBool('Header','Key',true);
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;
```

when debugging the code, the debugger showed hanging on the Create factory of TForm

```
  Inherited Create(AOwner);
```

Question time:
Why does the Delphi hang when query ini file? the ini file is a few keys big, standing in the [64k windows API](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/tinifile.htm) limit. What does the even OnCreate has to do with this?

> INI Limitations and Downsides The TIniFile class uses the Windows API
>   which imposes a limit of 64KB on INI files. If you need to store more
>   than 64KB of data, you should use the TMemIniFile.

update:
so many comments ill try to relate.

i say the reason i blame this code, is a simple "try and see". i removed the ini file call, from the on create, and the code run smoothly , instant window open. when compiling with the ini file call on onCreate, the software hangs 8 seconds.
moved the call from onCreate to the constructor Create, the code works smoothly.

the ini file is a local file, it is on a local directory, and the software was the only one calling this file, not a network file. on drive c\folder\foler\filename.ini, windows.

doing the `CheckBox1.Checked := true`, gives a half a second delay(fast).
doing

```
  with TIniFile.Create(Path + '\FileName.INI') do
    try

    finally
      Free;
    end;
```

half a second delay, (fast).
buy placing back the code still yields 8 seconds delay.
moving the code from OnCreate to Constructor Create half a second delay (fast).

so i am unsure as to why this is happening.

Comment: You say the debugger points to a certain line as the hang, but your code doesn't contain such a line. Why do you blame the INI code when the debugger blames something else?

Comment: Where does Path point to?  I have seen very slow access using TIni file with Memory locations.  There is some locking and re-reading that happens with TIniFile to support multi-process access.  In my case changing to TMemIni file resulted in a large speedup as everything is read into memory on the open.

Comment: @MarkElder, TMemInifile is the way to go when you only read from the INI and need to access it often. In addition I suggest to use only one central instance instead of dynamically create the instance in every place it is needed.

Comment: Just saw the typo in my comment - I meant "network locations".  Not sure what "memory locations" means :-)

Comment: What if you comment out the .ini stuff and go with:
CheckBox1.Checked := true;
Is that fast?

Comment: I highly doubt the INI file has anything to do with your problem. As mentioned before, your debugger stops on a line of code before the INI code is even reached. My guess is that you have a component or control in your form, such as a database connection, which is doing some lengthy work upon creation.

Comment: Create a small test program and try to replicate the issue.